# How to push current branch to remote without setting upstream?

Tags: git

I can push branch to remote:

```
git push --set-upstream origin 293-error-pages
```

I can push branch without setting upstream *by specifying current branch explicitly*:

```
git push origin 293-error-pages
```

How to push current branch to remote? (and not specify its name explicitly)

```
git push origin
```

Tells me:

```
fatal: The current branch 293-error-pages has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin 293-error-pages
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To push current branch to remote you should set/configure `push.default` to 'current'

```
git config --global push.default current
```

> **push.default**
> Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is explicitly given.
> current - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the
> receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your default for `push.default`, you can use the following command:

```
git push origin HEAD
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-codegitpushoriginHEADcode

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
git push <remotename> <localcommit>:<remotebranch>
```

This will push `<localcommit>` to `<remotebranch>` or create it on server `<remotename>`